# A simple way to write an already running event_loop to add a new task

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

What I want to do is to **new add tasks later** on to a long-lasting (and preferably empty) event_loop.

I also want to end the event_loop at an arbitrary time.

This code is intended to be run on a server.

I've tried it myself

(1)Use call_soon, create_task, and ensure_future when creating tasks

(2)Use run_forever to run the task

I wrote the following code that I thought I could implement in my own way.

However, this code will do something that **doesn't need to be done** every 10 seconds.

Moreover i can't arbitrarily end the event_loop.

In summary, please tell me the following two points

(1)How to make the first event_loop simple and not block tasks that will be added later

(2)How to stop event_loop at any given time

```
import threading
import asyncio


async def long_task():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        i = i+1


async def create_long_task(loop):
    t = loop.create_task(long_task())
    await t


def run_long_task():
    loop.run_until_complete(create_long_task(loop))


def new_task():
    print('----------------------------')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_long_task)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=new_task)
thread2.start()
```

Postscript

I read the comments and rewrote it.

But I can't achieve it even with this code.

If I change "await asyncio.sleep(3)" to "time.sleep(3)" in "long_task()", "new_task()" will be blocked.

Rewriting it to "await time.sleep(3)" gives the following error.

[TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression]

How do I rewrite it?

What I'd like to do is to create an empty event_loop first since I don't want to add more event_loops, and then add the necessary tasks to the event_loop.

I want to start the server and have an empty loop running, and then add tasks as needed.

```
import threading
import asyncio


async def long_task():
   i = 0
   while True:
       print(i)
       await asyncio.sleep(10)
       i = i+1


async def create_long_task(loop):
   t = loop.create_task(long_task())
   await t


def run_long_task():
   loop.run_until_complete(create_long_task(loop))


async def new_task():
   i = 0
   while True:
       print("---{}--".format(i))
       await asyncio.sleep(10)
       i = i+1


def add_task(loop):
   t = loop.create_task(new_task())
   t


def add_thread(loop):
   thread = threading.Thread(
       target=add_task, args=(loop,))
   thread.start()
   thread.join
   print("new thread end")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_long_task)
thread1.start()

add_thread(loop)
```

Comment: you run `new_task` in different thread and it may not have acccess to loop in other thread. Besides some frameworks doesn't like to run in many threads. You should rather run only `long_task()` in separated thread - and it could use normal `time.sleep()` - and rest you could run in current/main thread so you could add `new_task` to loop

Comment: @furas 
I've added a note, if you'd like to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` to send tasks to a running loop. You can start a loop by running `run_forever` in a separate thread, and then submit tasks to that loop, just as you wanted:

```
import threading, asyncio, time

def run_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def new_task():
    print('a')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('b')

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(loop,)).start()

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(new_task(), loop)
    # sleep while the task runs in the background
    time.sleep(2)
    print('exiting')
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. I was able to do what I wanted to do.